# Convert this .RDL code into readable SQL query code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdl

I am studying a long query that serves as a dataset in a rdl report file, but I was stopped to this as I try to convert it to SQL code.

I am new to this, so please help to enlighten what this code is about.

```
IIf (Parameters!ORDER_SUPPORT_ID.Value ="",""," AND " &amp; ReportingServices.ReportUtilities.SQLHelper.ToSQL("CLT.ORDER_SUPPORT_ID", Parameters!ORDER_SUPPORT_ID.Value, "NUM")) &amp; "
```

i believe IIF is like an If-else concept in programming in general

Comment: [CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358260/oracle-case-statement)?

Comment: yes it is part of the where clause of the overall statement...

Comment: A common expression for optional search parameters in SQL using parametrized queries is `WHERE (@parameter1 is null OR column1 = @parameter1) and (@parameter2 is null OR column2 = @parameter2)`

Comment: is that the actual conversion? counterpart